# What's different for ldconfig & modprobe

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel

When I follow the zfs install guide in CentOS

I found out it should use `ldconfig` after finish the source building

But when I use the `zfs` command，it tell me, I should type command: `/sbin/modprobe zfs`

So, I am interested with what's the different between `ldconfig` and `modprobe`，is it ldconfig for user space process & modprobe for kernel space process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldconfig` and `modprobe` are two very different programs

`ldconfig` essentially caches all your shared libraries so when a program needs it at runtime, it won't have to search the filesystem to find the shared library. From the man page:

```
ldconfig  creates  the  necessary links and cache to the most recent shared 
libraries found in the directories specified on the command line...

The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so. ldconfig checks 
the header and filenames of the libraries it encounters when determining which 
versions should have their links updated.
```

`modprobe` adds or removes a module from the linux kernel. Modules are pretty much pieces of code that can be plugged in and out of the kernel.

> is it ldconfig for user space process & modprobe for kernel space process?

Shared libraries are used by run-time programs while modules are removable pieces of kernel code.

Comment: It seems that if I only use ldconfig，the run-time program known ‘it’ have some api，however，what these api to do is provided by `modprobe` module？

Comment: If by API you mean communication between user-space and kernel-space then this can be done in many ways. Some of them are: virtual filesystem, linux calls, d-bus, netlink, e.t.c. It all depends on how you write your module